# How to left join multiple one to many tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

i have a problem with joining three tables in mysql.

lets say we have a table named `posts` which I keep my entries in it, i have a table named `likes` which i store user_id's and post_id's in and a third table named `comments` which i store user_id's and post_id's and comment's text in it.

I need a query that fetches list of my entries, with number of likes and comments for each entry.

Im using this query:

```
SELECT posts.id, count(comments.id) as total_comments, count(likes.id) as total_likes
FROM `posts`
LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON comments.post_id = posts.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN likes ON likes.post_id = posts.id
GROUP BY posts.id
```

but there is a problem with this query, if comments are empty for an item, likes count is just ok, but lets say if an entry has 2 comments and 4 likes, both total_comments and total_likes will be "8", meaning that mysql multiplies them.
I'm confused and I dont know what whould I do.

Thanks in advace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `count(distinct comments.id)` and `count(distinct likes.id)`, provided these ids are unique.

Answer (score 4):

Well this is one way to approach it (assuming mysql allows derived tables):

```
SELECT posts.id, comments.total_comments, likes.total_likes 
FROM `posts` 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select post_id,  count(id) as total_comments from  comments) comments 
    ON comments.post_id = posts.id  
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select post_id,  count(id) as total_likes from  likes) likes 
    ON likes.post_id = posts.id
```

You could also use correlated subqueries. You may want a case statment inthere to account for putting in a 0 when there are no matched records.

Let's try a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT posts.id, 
(select count(Id) from comments where post_id = posts.id) as total_comments, 
(select count(Id) from likes where post_id = posts.id) as total_likes 
FROM `posts`
```

Comment: thanks, but this query returned 12 likes and 2 comments for first record (it has 4 likes and 2 comments), and NULL for all other rows.

Comment: looks like the correlated subquery route might be best

Comment: I haven't heard a thing about them.

Comment: You should really try your best to avoid subqueries

Comment: I agree thats why it wasn;t my first suggestion