# Mysql Left join multiple 1 to many tables

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I am trying to get the following data from 3/4 tables in 1 `Mysql query`, wondering if it is possible ? The tables are

```
TOPIC
topicid (FK)(PK)
groupid
topic
user

LIKED
likeid
topicid (FK)
user

COMMENT
commentid (PK)
topicid (FK)
comment
user
```

I write my topics and store in TOPIC Table with unique topicid. I group each topic using groupid.
Other tables may have 0 or more data per topicid.

I am trying to get each topic for a particular group and also get other datas from the concerned Tables. I checked [How to left join multiple one to many tables in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650914/how-to-left-join-multiple-one-to-many-tables-in-mysql) and got few idea but that is for the count while I wanted to get details from that table (users who like), and (user and their comment).

I have tried

```
SELECT t.topicid,
       topic,
       group_concat(DISTINCT likeid,l.user SEPARATOR '|'),
       group_concat(DISTINCT commentid,comment,c.user SEPARATOR '|') AS comments
FROM TOPIC t
LEFT JOIN LIKE l ON l.topicid = t.topicid
LEFT JOIN COMMENT c ON c.topicid = t.topicid
WHERE t.groupid='some_value'
GROUP BY t.topicid
```

While this works partly e.g. I do get the details but only if there is one topic in a group. If there are 2 or more topics in a group then the `concat` details are stored in the first record only and the later topics show no likes and comments.

Can someone please help me to correct this or any particular `Mysql function` I am missing

Comment: I'm confused.  You are joining and grouping by `topicid`.  Then you are complaining that multiple topics don't get multiple values when they are in a group.  Do you want to sort by groupid?

Comment: Could you make a sqlfiddle with sample data, and show what the desired result should be?

Comment: @Barmar I tried sqlfiddle at [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9ab57/1/0) .

Comment: @GordonLinoff If I group by groupid I will not get separate topics for that group.

The result I desire is 

the 3 `topicid,topics` for `groupid= '1'`

number of likes,user who liked for each `topicid` got for this `groupid`

number of comments, user and comment for each `topicid` got for this `groupid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very very sorry for wasting your time, after thorough re-check I found my table data were wrong (checked after making sqlfiddle thanks @Barmar).

I was by mistake inserting wrong data in like and comment table. So Likes and comments for 2nd topic `topicid='2'` of `groupid='1'` were inserted by mistake as `topicid='1'` that is why the details only showed in 1st topic and nothing came out for second topic.

The SQL above is absolutely correct and thankyou for helping me find the fault. 
Extremely sorry for posting again.